# Solving a system of equations with answer required in specific format

Tags: linear-algebra

Ive been asked the following question and I'm not sure how to approach it.

Solve the system

\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2-5x_3=2 \\
6x_1+7x_2+4x_3=7
\end{cases}

The answer is required to be in the form of

$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}...\\ ...\\...\end{bmatrix}$+s$\begin{bmatrix}...\\ ...\\...\end{bmatrix}$

I know how to solve systems using REF and RREF or converting linear equations to matrix equations and solve using inverses. But Im not sure how to solve using the answer format above. Any tips? Don't give answer outright if at all possible but some hints would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the RREF, you will get

$x_1=7+39x_3$

and

$x_2=-5-34x_3.$

Now put $s=x_3$ an we derive

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\ -5\\0\end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}39\\ -34\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: lol, thanks @Fred, I was hoping to not to be given the answer but alas I know how to do it now and I have a few more questions that are similar so I'll do them independently. Thanks again though. You've answered a number of my questions now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  Evidently, the solution set is $1$-dimensional.

Now use row-reduction to find it.

Comment: Im thinking what you mean is the answer is a line. I see there are three columns and only two equations giving at least one free variable. I can solve for x's using techniques previously mentioned but what's throwing me off is the $+s[...]$ bit. Is there a certain method that gets the answer in that form?

Comment: It should be easy to put it in that form at the end, after row-reduction and back substitution.

Comment: got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the first equation by $4$ and the second by $5$ we get
$$x_1=\frac{43}{34}-\frac{39}{34}x_2$$
so $x_2=-5+34x_3$ and we get
$$[x_1,x_2,x_3]=[7,-5,0]+t[39,34,1]$$ where $t\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we get an augmented matrix that represents the linear system of equations.
$$
  A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 1 & -5 & 2 \\
    6 & 7 & 4 & 7 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Then we perform the matrix operations to get $A$ into Reduced row echelon form giving us:
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 0 & -39 & 7 \\
    0 & 1 & 34 & -5 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]
$$

This means that $x_3$ is a free variable and we have infinite solutions to this system.

We can now represent the solution as:
$$
  x_3 = s \in \Bbb{R} \\
  x_2 + 34x_3 = -5 \iff x_2 =  \\
  x_1 - 39x_3 = 7 \iff x_1 = 7 + 39s \\
$$

All that is left is to represent this in a Matrix form which can be done as so:
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    7 + 39s \\
    -5 - 34s \\
    s \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe at this point it is fair to leave the rest of the conversion as an exercise to the reader :)